# How to disable the security setting on a Bixolon SRP-350IIObe

Tags: ios, printing, bluetooth

I currently have a need to disable the bluetooth security on a Bixolon SRP-350IIObe thermal printer. The pairing process of having to type in the pin to connect to the printer isn't a positive thing for my use case of this printer. The printer is currently in iOS only mode, using MFI.

According to bixolon's documentation it should be possible as bixolon states the following

> 3-4 Register this Printer form the search results. 
>   - If a security setting is enabled, register after entering the PIN Code. 
>   (PIN Code=Pass Key: password of the Bluetooth device, Default code: 0000)

Source:
http://www.bixolonusa.com/upload/download/srp-350iiobe_bluetooth%20connection%20manual_english_rev_1_00.pdf

I have been searching out the information through the bixolon site's documents, but have yet to find any information on how to achieve this.

Any help or ideas on a resolution would be appreciated.

Edit:

In light of receiving downvotes with no justification as to why I feel that perhaps I should include more of a reason as to the need to disable the security setting on my own SRP350. I plan to have many of these printers and I won't be doing the pairing work on them so it will be easier to just tell someone how to pair without the passcode issue. I am writing against the bixolon api and the pairing process will be done by non tech oriented people at offsite locations between the printer and iOS devices.

Thank you.

Comment: Not sure I understand why this question deserved a negative rep. It is a proper question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more digging it would appear the utility to achieve the bluetooth settings and pin code changes is called Unified POS Utility. The disc is included with the printer and the utility will run on a windows machine. After connecting to the printer you can go to the VMSM (Virtual Memory Setting Manager) and then bluetooth settings. It is in this menu you can edit the pin code and even disable the need for a security layer during the pairing process.

The download for the utility is found here > http://www.bixolonusa.com/html/en/download/download_product.xhtml?prod_id=82